# how to get search form on selectlist

Tags: form

Immediately after selecting pull-down on the visualforce screen, put the selected value "hoge" on the aid parameter of the GET request,
For example, I would like to make a request like https://salesforce.com/apex/abc?Aid=hoge.

I'm sorry, but I do not know how to do it,
How can I do it?

By the way, if you feel like the following, because it becomes ajax, url will not change.

```
<Apex:selectList value = "{!aId}" size = "1">
     <Apex:selectOptions value = "{!aList}" />
     <Apex:actionSupport action = "{!change}" event = "onchange" />
</Apex:selectList>
```

I want to create a permanent link-like page so that it can be received with get like the following.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [PageReference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_system_pagereference.htm) class in your controller. This class allows you to redirect to a new page with parameters.
When your list value is changed, the Change method is called in your controller.
Here's what to put in your method:

```
public PageReference change(){
       PageReference pageRef = Page.abc;
       pageRef.getParameters().put('Aid', this.aId);
       pageRef.setRedirect(true);
       return pageRef;
}
```

Comment: You're welcome from the bottom of my heart